# How to preserve php session variables when redirecting to https

Tags: php

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to preserve my php session variables once i do a https redirect like this:

```
$location = 'https://' . BASE_URL . 'billing.php';
header("Location: $location");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [session_set_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Make sure the `domain` parameter is like: `.yoursite.com` with a dot at the beginning and that will make it match for any subdomains of yoursite.com.

Then make sure the `secure` parameter is set to `true`, which will allow it to be sent over a secure connection.

You can view your current configuration with [session_get_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php).

Comment: This did it.  Now i'm getting the session back and forth from http to https and visa versa.  Thank you.